# DB2 How to convert the following "with temp as" into a normal select statement

Tags: db2, sql-insert, with-statement

I'm trying to do an insert with this "with" statement but it seems like it supports select statement only, therefore I want to convert it into select statement. I'm just amazed on how this is working. Got a similar example on stack and changed it to fit my needs.

```
with temp (startdate, enddate, maxdate) as (
    select min(salesdate) startdate, min(salesdate)+3 months enddate, max(salesdate) maxdate
    from SALES
    union all
    select startdate + 3 months + 1 days, enddate + 3 months + 1 days, maxdate from temp 
    where enddate <= maxdate
)
select startdate, min(enddate, maxdate) from temp;
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: It seems my query is misunderstood. Here is the pseudo code of what the query is supposed to be doing. The query is returning the expected result which is pretty amazing to me. I don't know how the recursive doesn't overlap after I added 1 day. After writing the pseudo code, I see that the `select startdate + 3 months + 1 days` should have been written as `select enddate + 1 days` which logically says what it's supposed to do instead of magically work:

```
rows = []
startdate = min(salesdate)
enddate = startdate + 3 months
maxdate = max(salesdate)
i = 0;
do {
    rows[i++] = [startdate, min(enddate, maxdate)] // min for final iteration where enddate > maxdate.
    startdate = enddate + 1 days
    enddate = enddate + 1 days + 3 months // aka: startdate + 3 months
} while (enddate <= maxdate)
return rows
```

Hence, I've broken a huge date range into smaller chunks of 3 months ranges. Whether it is exactly 90 days or 91 days is not important, as long as I get every single date without gap and without overlap.

Comment: You want to consider `enddate` to be **exclusive** - that is, compared with `<`.  For one thing, that's going to make all your queries much easier to understand, and make the recursive query much simpler: `SELECT enddate, enddate + 3 MONTHS, maxdate FROM Temp`.  If your original version is used for a long enough run, it's possible for it to skip days, or double up on days (because the ends of the month aren't all the same).

Comment: I don't understand your concern. Maybe you misunderstood my query? The `+3 months` is a hard increment. I want my next rows to always be incremented by 3 months. I could've done 91 days too and it makes almost no difference (other than how they translate month to date). What it does is it starts out with `startdate` and `startdate + 3 months as enddate`, `then recursively add 3 months+1day` (so the day won't repeat on the next row) to both start date and end date for the next row. The recursion ends when I've reached the maxdate (which technically is the real `enddate`).

Comment: I've added the pseudo code for better understanding. The problem with SQL is that it is very hard for people who did not write it to understand it, like those many nested sub selects. Or you're trying to tell me the correct way and I'm misunderstand you. In that case, thousand apologies.

Comment: ...does the fact that your start date is a different day-of-month with every increment not seem strange to you?  Normally I'd expect it to be the same.  Since you're concerned about overlapping days, the normal solution is to use an exclusive bound - `<` - instead of adding 1 and using an inclusive bound `<=`.

Comment: I see what you mean by days being incremented. The answer is no, I just want to divide the operations in chunks to prevent transaction log issue. I still don't get your points on the < sign. The <= is not for non-overlapping. It is a recursion stopping point (base case?). I can decide whether to stop the recursion at i < 10 or i <= 10 is no different to readability. Not sure how this will look but this is the first few rows of my result: `STARTDATE ENDDATE
5/1/2012 8/1/2012
8/2/2012 11/2/2012
11/3/2012 2/3/2013
2/4/2013 5/4/2013`. As you can see, no overlaps and no missing dates.

Comment: I'm not talking about the actual `maxdate` comparison, I'm talking about what's being used to generate the grouping.  You have an implicit inclusive upper bound, not a spelled out one.  If I was reading the output of that report, I'd be looking at you strange for the dates not matching up.  Try switching the recursive `SELECT` to what I posted earlier, and see what results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about your decision, that a query with a recursive common table expression (RCTE) is "not normal". IBM calls it as 'select-statement' and considers it as normal. If it's some educational question, and you don't want to use RCTE due to some reason, then consider the the following example.

```
select s + (3*(x.i-1)) month start, s + (3*x.i) month - 1 day end
from table(values (date('2011-01-01'), date('2012-01-01'))) d(s, e)
, xmltable('for $id in (1 to $e) return <i>{number($id)}</i>' 
  passing ((year(e)-year(s))*12 + (month(e)-month(s)))/3 as "e"
  columns i int path '.'
) x;

START       END
----------  ----------
2011-01-01  2011-03-31
2011-04-01  2011-06-30
2011-07-01  2011-09-30
2011-10-01  2011-12-31
;
```

It's a little bit complicated, since you must pass desired number of rows to return to the xmltable table function, which returns a single column with values 1 to N. In other words you must compute desired number of 3-months intervals and pass it to the function.

(R)CTE can't be used in the UPDATE/DELETE statements, where you are able to use so called fullselect statements only (they don't allow CTEs). If you really need to use CTE for UPDATE/DELETE as in this case, you can do one of the following:

If you ARE ABLE to compute a temporary result set for whole delete/update statement, you can do something like this (I don't use here RCTE for simplicity, but a simple CTE only):

```
with a (id) as (values 1)
select count(1)
from old table(
delete from test t 
where exists (select 1 from a where a.id=t.id)
);
```

If you ARE NOT ABLE to compute a temporary result set for whole delete/update statement, you can create a table/scalar function with the corresponding parameters, where you are able to use your RCTE. This function can be used in the outer statement afterwards.

Comment: Oh no, not at all. The recursive query is beautiful. The problem was the "With" statement that comes with it. I did some googling and some answer suggested "with temp as" type of query only allow for "select" statement, not for updates or inserts. Therefore, I needed to convert it to a normal select statement. After finding out, that "with temp as" can be used for insert, I posted my own answer but I was still interested on how to convert that original query into non-with query.

Comment: "(R)CTE can't be used in the UPDATE/DELETE statements".
That is not true. I was able to use insert and cursor by simply moving the insert/cursor to the top (before the "with temp as" statement). Please check my own answer for a sample insert statement.

Comment: This IS true. Your answer was about INSERT, but I mentioned UPDATE/DELETE. If you don’t agree with this, please, provide your example of UPDATE/DELETE using CTE, and not using SELECT from data-change operation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to insert it by moving the insert statement in front of the "with" statement. Copying answer here so I know next time. Although, I'm still interested in seeing how to convert it to a pure select statement. Will select that answer as the correct answer.

```
insert into my_temp_table
    with temp (startdate, enddate, maxdate) as (
      select min(salesdate) startdate, min(salesdate)+3 months enddate, max(salesdate) maxdate
      from SALES
      union all
      select startdate + 3 months + 1 days, enddate + 3 months + 1 days, maxdate from temp 
      where enddate <= maxdate
   )
   select startdate, min(enddate, maxdate) from temp;
```

Comment: There is no such meaning in db2 as “pure select”. It’s better to follow standard naming conventions described below the [Queries and table expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0004116.html) link. It’s not clear what you want to achieve. Can you be more specific about this?

Comment: I'm trying to partition one 6 year date range into small chunks of 3 months range and insert it into a table. My table would have the following rows (assuming the date range is from 1/1/2011 to 1/1/2012):
`1/1/2011  -  4/1/2011, `
`4/2/2011  -  7/2/2011, `, etcetc..
`x/x/2012  -  1/1/2012`
The query I posted does a recursive increment of 3 months and stops when enddate <= maxdate. I simply want to convert that query (which uses with statement) to a normal select statement.